# Check if a variable of the for-each is equal with an XML entry

Tags: xslt, xhtml, xpath

I'm trying to add the attribute 'selected' to `<option>`. I've tried various ways and I can't get it working. This is how I'm trying it:

```
<xsl:for-each select="page/index/values/albums">
    <option>
        <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="id" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="page/index/values/album = id">
             <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="name" />
    </option>
</xsl:for-each>
```

What is the correct form for the `<xsl:if />`?

**Edit:**

My XML file:

```
<page>
    <index>
        <values>
            <album>2</album>

            <albums>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>Album #1</name>
            </albums>

            <albums>
                <id>2</id>
                <name>Album #2</name>
            </albums>
        </values>
    </index>
</page>
```

Output:

```
<option value="1">Album #1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Album #2</option>
```

Comment: What does the XML you are trying to transform look like (just the relevant pieces, please)?

Comment: Palaus: Your test condition is wrong. Inside `for-each` content template, the context node is `albums`. So I think there is no `albums/page/index/values/album`. Provide input sample.

Comment: And the output you want?

Comment: Some parts of your question seem to have disappeared. Maybe some angle-brackets in the text? Try escaping those words with backticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath you are using is incorrect:

```
<xsl:if test="page/index/values/album = id">
```

Is should be:

```
<xsl:if test="../album = id">
```

You are in the context of the different `albums` nodes, so you need to go to the parent node `values` before getting the value of `album`.

Alternatively, you need to root your XPath:

```
<xsl:if test="/page/index/values/album = id">
```

Comment: I added the XML file that I'm transforming. page/index/values/albums have nothing to do with page/index/values/album .

The second is the id of the selected album for a `<select>`.

Answer (score 1):

The test condition should be:

```
id = ../album
```

**Edit**: Now with desired output, use this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="values">
        <select>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="albums"/>
        </select>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="albums">
        <option value="{id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </option>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="id"/>
    <xsl:template match="id[.=../../album]">
        <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Album #1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Album #2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form for adding an attribute is right, but as @Alejandro pointed out, your if test condition is probably wrong. Especially the left side of the "=". These XPath expressions are relative to the context node, which is `page/index/values/albums`.